# Why won't my pi appear on my PC network in file explorer?

Tags: networking, server

I'm trying to set up my raspberry pi as a media server for my home network. 
I followed the tutorial here: http://www.howtogeek.com/139433/how-to-turn-a-raspberry-pi-into-a-low-power-network-storage-device/

I believe I have done everything correctly. I can ssh into my pi using putty and I can see that my pi is connected to my network when I log into my router. But the pi won't appear in my file explorer. One issue I was having when I first connected the hard drive to the pi is that it wasn't getting enough power. The hard drive would briefly power up and then turn off. I fixed this by going into the pi config.txt file and adding "max_usb_current=1". The hard drive then stayed on with no issues. Could the problem be its still not getting enough power?

Comment: I recommend getting an official Raspberry Pi power supply, DO NOT force maximum current through the USB ports - bad idea.

Comment: @DarthVader Thanks, I just bought a powered usb hub that I will use to connect the hard drive to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that samba shares have ever shown up automatically for me. If you click into the navigation textbox at the top of your file explorer window you can get to the pi by prefixing its IP address with a double backslash. For example: `\\192.168.1.63`

Comment: Thank you! That worked. And I was then able to map it to the z: drive on my computer so I don't have to enter the ip every time to access it.

Comment: No problem. If you're happy that your question's been answered it's useful if you [mark the answer as accepted](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).